# Google closure gives error while javascript minificatation

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

I am using google-closure-compiler grunt task to minify javascript files. I've defined task like : -

```
'closure-compiler': {
        deviceDetails: {

            files: {
                'target.min.js: 'source.js'
            },
            options: {
              compilation_level: 'SIMPLE'
            }
            //  args: [
            //     '--js', 'source.js',
            //     '--compilation_level', 'SIMPLE',
            //     '--js_output_file', 'out.js',
            //     '--debug'
            //     ]

        }
```

This gives me an error

```
  [ { '29': 1,
_state: 2,
_result: [Error: not implemented],
_subscribers: [] } ]
Warning: Compilation error Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Earlier I was facing promise issue , for that I installed pollyfill module.

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

I am running npm 1.3.10 version and Unfortunately, I can't upgrade it right now.

Also , followed alternative approach of using args.. still facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

So after bit analysis, I am using below two  grunt plugin's

```
1. grunt-closure-tools

2. google-closure-compiler
```

> Its was a problem with legacy npm version.